# why this Dijkstra algorithm not working for this particular input?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I have implemented [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). 
But it does not work when input is the following:

```
1
6 7
1 2 5
2 3 2
3 4 3
1 4 9
4 5 2
5 6 3
1 6 2
1
```

I ran it in debug mode, to understand what was wrong.  It appeared that the node 5 was not inserted in cell. I can't find out why.

Here the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

struct compare
{
    bool operator()(pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) const
    {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }

};

void printResults(vector<int> vec, int starting)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vec[i] == numeric_limits<int>::max() && i != starting)
        {
            cout << -1 << " ";
        }
        else if (i != starting)
        {
            cout << vec[i] << " ";
        }
    }

}
void djkstra(vector<vector<pair<int, int>>>&vec, int starting, int number_of_vertices)
{
    int max = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    set <pair<int, int>,compare> queue;
    vector<bool> visited(number_of_vertices + 1, false);
    vector<int> distances(number_of_vertices + 1, max);
    vector<int> parents(number_of_vertices + 1, -1);
    queue.insert(make_pair(starting, 0));
    distances[starting] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_vertices-1; i++)
    {
        pair<int, int> minElem = *queue.begin(); //take min elem
        queue.erase(minElem);
        vector<pair<int, int>> adjacents = vec[minElem.first];//take neighbours
        for (int j = 0; j<adjacents.size(); j++)
        {
            pair<int, int> node = adjacents[j];
            if (!visited[node.first])
            {
                if (distances[node.first]> distances[minElem.first] + node.second) //if we have found smaller distance
                {

                    if (queue.find(make_pair(node.first, distances[node.first])) != queue.end())
                    {
                        queue.erase(make_pair(node.first, distances[node.first]));
                        queue.insert(make_pair(node.first, distances[minElem.first] + node.second));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queue.insert(make_pair(node.first, distances[minElem.first] + node.second));
                        cout<<distances[minElem.first] + node.second<<endl;

                    }

                    distances[node.first] = distances[minElem.first] + node.second;
                }

            }

        }
        visited[minElem.first] = true;

    }
    printResults(distances,starting);

}

int main()
{
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < test; i++)
    {
        int nodes, edges;
        cin >> nodes >> edges;
        vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> vec(nodes + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < edges; j++)
        {
            int src, des, weight;
            cin >> src >> des >> weight;
            vec[src].push_back(make_pair(des, weight));
            vec[des].push_back(make_pair(src, weight));

        }

        int starting;
        cin >> starting;
        djkstra(vec, starting, nodes);

    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you stepped through with the debugger, where did the 5 go instead?

Comment: it was not added to the queue.So on first step queue has node 1,after that it has node 2,4,6,then  minimum node is 6,where it must add node 5 to the queue but it did not do it

Comment: The input is short: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb33d0267af082f

Comment: @sehe you are right.The should be one more line,where you specify starting node.In this case it is 1

Comment: `if (distances[node.first] > distances[minElem.first] + node.second)` - this compares... a distance to (distance + vertex id)?! Also, your ajdacency list repeats the starting vertex of each outgoing edge, when that's known in an adjacencylist

Comment: Wait. Is `pair<int, int>` a pair of `node_id, priority`? What algorithm have you implemented anyways? Why is everthing opaque? We have `vector<vector<pair<int, int> > >` and now we find out that _that_ `pair<int, int>` maybe fundamentally different from the one you compare with `compare`? Consider fixing the types (use `size_t`, `unsigned` where appropriate, name `compare` to `EdgeLessByTarget` or `ByPriority`, name things like `using Edge = pair<unsigned, unsigned>; using MinElement = pair<unsigned, Weight>; using Queue = set<MinElement, ByPriority>;`. ...

Comment: In other words, make your code express intent, making it readable. I promise that when you do, the error will probably *leap* out to you. It's like keeping your drawer tidy so you can find your stuff.

Comment: I mean. Why is `vec` the name of your distances vector, but /also/ of an adjacency list? (That's like saying your bicycle is "moving parts organized in vertical fashion" or your netflix subscription is "your contract"), Why is `i` in the loop inside `printResult` an int (should be `unsigned` or better yet, `Vertex`, _and_ be called `v`). I'm still trying to make sense of it.

Comment: pair<int,int> --first is the node_id,second is weight from src.vec is adjacency list.Distances are saved in distance vector.

Comment: adjacency list repeats first when it's know,but I always test if vertex is  visited or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507039/why-this-dijkstra-algorithm-not-working-for-this-particular-input/46749485#comment80454899_46507039) trying [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507039/why-this-dijkstra-algorithm-not-working-for-this-particular-input/46749485#comment80454998_46507039) make [sense of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507039/why-this-dijkstra-algorithm-not-working-for-this-particular-input/46749485#comment80455009_46507039) your [question code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507039/why-this-dijkstra-algorithm-not-working-for-this-particular-input/46749485#comment80455382_46507039), I arrived upon a clean re-write according to [the Wikipedia Pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode)

I *think* (because you still never showed the output you get which is supposedly wrong), your cardinal error is just using `set<>`:

**<kbd>[Bugged Version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef4e06bd748775ef)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using Vertex  = unsigned;
using Weight  = double;

struct OutEdge {
    Vertex node;
    Weight weight;
    bool operator<(OutEdge const& o) const { return weight < o.weight; }
};

using OutEdges     = std::vector<OutEdge>;
using AdjList      = std::vector<OutEdges>;
using Distances    = std::vector<Weight>;
using Predecessors = std::vector<Vertex>;

static Weight const INFINITY = std::numeric_limits<Weight>::max();
static Vertex const UNDEFINED {-1u};

using namespace std;

void print_graph(AdjList const& graph) {
    for (Vertex v = 1; v < graph.size(); v++) {
        std::cout << v << " -";
        for (auto& adj : graph[v])
            std::cout << " " << adj.node << "(" << adj.weight << ")";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void printResults(Distances const& dist, Vertex starting) {
    for (Vertex v = 0; v < dist.size(); v++) {
        std::cout << starting << " -> " << v << ": ";
        if (dist[v] == INFINITY && v != starting) {
            cout << -1 << " ";
        } else { // if (v != starting) {
            cout << dist[v] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

Distances dijkstra(AdjList const& graph, Vertex source) {
    std::set<OutEdge> Q;

    vector<bool> visited(graph.size(), false);
    Distances    dist(graph.size(), INFINITY);  // Unkown distance from source
    Predecessors prev(graph.size(), UNDEFINED); // Previous node in optimal path from source

    dist[source] = 0; // Distance from source to source

    for (Vertex v = 1; v < graph.size(); v++)
        Q.insert({v, dist[v]});

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        Vertex u = Q.begin()->node;
        visited[u] = true;
        Q.erase(Q.begin());

        for (auto& v : graph[u]) { // for each neighbour
            if (visited[v.node]) // where v is still in Q.
                continue;

            Weight alt = dist[u] + v.weight;

            if (alt < dist[v.node]) // A short path to v has been found
            {
                dist[v.node] = alt;
                prev[v.node] = u;

                // update prio
                auto it = std::find_if(Q.begin(), Q.end(), [&](auto& oe) { return oe.node == v.node; });
                if (it != Q.end()) {
                    Q.erase(it);
                    Q.insert({v.node, alt});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dist;
}

int main() {
    size_t test;
    cin >> test;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        size_t nodes, edges;
        cin >> nodes >> edges;
        nodes += 1; // hack to avoid converting ids to base-0

        AdjList adj(nodes);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < edges; j++) {
            Vertex src, des;
            Weight weight;

            cin >> src >> des >> weight;
            assert(weight>=0);

            adj[src].push_back({des, weight});
            adj[des].push_back({src, weight});
        }

        print_graph(adj);

        Vertex starting;
        cin >> starting;
        auto d = dijkstra(adj, starting);
        printResults(d, starting);
    }
}
```

Which prints the result as:

```
1 -> 0: -1 
1 -> 1: 0 
1 -> 2: 5 
1 -> 3: 7 
1 -> 4: 9 
1 -> 5: -1 
1 -> 6: 2
```

> ***NOTE*** You had at least one more bug in `djkstra` [sic] where you did
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i<number_of_vertices-1; i++)
> ```
>
> That `-1` seems to be completely wrong (if anything, it "should" have been `+1` although it was a ginormous code smell to have `+1` strewn about all of the code. See how I solved that in my version.

### Explanation

`std::set<>` models a container with unique elements. In this case the weight is the equivalence property and as such, all elements having identical weight are equivalent. At the very start the queue will contain at most 2 elements: 1 starting vertex (distance 0) and 1 of the other vertices that have all been seeded with the same distance (`INFINITY`; or `max` in your version).

This is going to sink your algorithm since many nodes are never visited (the algorithms stops as soon the queue is empty).

The fix is 5 letters: `s/set/multiset/`:

**<kbd>[Fixed Version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/965c79724949f7cf)</kbd>**

Prints:

```
1 -> 0: -1 
1 -> 1: 0 
1 -> 2: 5 
1 -> 3: 7 
1 -> 4: 7 
1 -> 5: 5 
1 -> 6: 2
```

---

Comment: I see,now.Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @sparrow2 Above all I hope you take away from this to (a) write expressive  code (expressive naming, deliberate typing) (b) debug (you would have spotted that `queue` had only 2 items). Oh, and before I forget, **(c) ask good questions** (complete, with  expectations and actual outcome)

Comment: you should use `binary_search` instead of `find_if` because the members in `set` are arranged already

Comment: @bigxiao You can't use `binary_search` because it returns bool, is suboptimal for non-random-access iterators and is just undefined behaviour when used with a comparator that doesn't match the ordering of the container elements. Perhaps you were thinking of `std::lower_bound`, `std::upper_bound` or `std::equal_range`, but that would still be suboptimal and UB. Instead perhaps you were thinking of `std::set::find` (which does implement binary search internally) **but** that won't work set is ordered by weight, not node. In other words: you were very confused.

Comment: oh,i've made a big mistake;

Comment: It happens :) Cheers

Comment: i think you should use `multiset` instead to represent priority-queue,because if you use `set`, the different pairs with the same value of weight  would be considered the same,and would not be inserted into the `set` actually.

Answer (score 2):

So, here's your graph:
[image]

The output of your program is **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb33d0267af082f)</kbd>**:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
        boost::no_property,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>
    >;

int main() {
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    int test; std::cin >> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) try {
        int nodes, edges;
        std::cin >> nodes >> edges;
        std::cout << "Nodes:" << nodes << " Edges:" << edges << "\n";

        Graph g(nodes + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < edges; j++) {
            int src, des, weight;
            std::cin >> src >> des >> weight;
            std::cout << "src:" << src << " des:" << des << " weight:" << weight << "\n";

            add_edge(src, des, weight, g);
        }

        boost::print_graph(g);

        int starting;
        std::cin >> starting;

        std::vector<int> dist(num_vertices(g));
        auto id = get(boost::vertex_index, g);

        dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, starting, 
                weight_map(get(boost::edge_weight, g))
                .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(dist.begin(), id))
            );

        std::cout << "Distances:\n";
        for (Graph::vertex_descriptor v = 0; v < num_vertices(g); v++) {
            std::cout << starting << " -> " << v << " = " << dist[v] << "\n";
        }
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Nodes:6 Edges:7
src:1 des:2 weight:5
src:2 des:3 weight:2
src:3 des:4 weight:3
src:1 des:4 weight:9
src:4 des:5 weight:2
src:5 des:6 weight:3
src:1 des:6 weight:2
0 --> 
1 --> 2 4 6 
2 --> 3 
3 --> 4 
4 --> 5 
5 --> 6 
6 --> 
Distances:
1 -> 0 = 2147483647
1 -> 1 = 0
1 -> 2 = 5
1 -> 3 = 7
1 -> 4 = 9
1 -> 5 = 11
1 -> 6 = 2
```

It's correct!

Here's the output of the algorithm, animating through all reachable target vertices:

[image]

It should be pretty self-evident that the *correct* distances are in fact:

```
1: 0  
2: 5  
3: 5+2 = 7  
4: 9 (5+2+3 is larger)  
5: 9+2 = 11  
6: 2 (both 5+2+3+2+3 and 9+2+3 are way larger)
```

### UPDATE UNDIRECTED

Yes, if it's undirected, [the outcome is different](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/347e4f7aedea0262):

[image]

Comment: Here's a minor variation of the same code used to generate the graphviz visualizations from:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e225d10dd44d54b (using [these commands](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25741284/) to create the animation)

Comment: This is true if graph is directed.In our case it is not

Comment: Literally, [`s/directedS/undirectedS/`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/347e4f7aedea0262). This making me wonder whether you've actually _read_ the code at all. And why you didn't include any expected results in your question. [Enhanced gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXotq.gif) in the answer